# How to capture Listbox selected item

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm

I am using MVVM and my code is as follows

```
  <ListBox Grid.Row="0"
             x:Name="myListBox" 
             ItemsSource="{Binding Path=MyClass}"
             ItemTemplate="{StaticResource MyDataTemplate}"
             SelectedItem="{Binding Path=SelectedItem}"
             HorizontalContentAlignment="Stretch">    
    </ListBox>
```

The ItemTemplate contains `TextBlock` and `Label`

and in my **ViewModel**

```
    public object SelectedItem
    {

        get
        {
            return _SelectedItem;
        }
        set
        {
            _SelectedItem = value;
            //Perform My Command
        }
    }
```

Its only after double click I am able to select the item.How can I make it to 
single mouse left click? Is there any way to convert double click to single click ?

Comment: Where do you double click?

Comment: @kyle i tried this with only single click, u can select the item. how did u do it with double click ?

Comment: Seems like some element inside a ListBoxItem handles the first MouseLeftButtonDown event. Therefore the ListBoxItem skips selection.

Comment: @Dhru'soni Where you click?

Comment: on the listbox item @aliboy38

Comment: @aliboy38 http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27897532/binding-list-of-objects-with-xaml/27898043#27898043 go throught this

Comment: @aliboy38 I have to perform double click on the item

Answer (score 0):

Try this. 
Add MouseUp event:

```
<ListBox Grid.Row="0"
         x:Name="myListBox" 
         MouseUp="myListBox_MouseUp"
         ItemsSource="{Binding Path=MyClass}"
         ItemTemplate="{StaticResource MyDataTemplate}"
         SelectedItem="{Binding Path=SelectedItem}"
         HorizontalContentAlignment="Stretch">
    </ListBox>
```

And in code behind:

```
private void myListBox_MouseUp(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e)
{

}
```

If you want to do this in MVVM You need to use Command for example

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure that this is what you want to, but this works for me:

```
<ListBox Grid.Row="6"
         x:Name="myListBox" 
         ItemsSource="{Binding Path=MyClassItems}"
         SelectedItem="{Binding Path=SelectedItem, Mode=TwoWay}"
         HorizontalContentAlignment="Stretch">
        <ListBox.ItemContainerStyle>
            <Style TargetType="{x:Type ListBoxItem}">
                <Setter Property="Template">
                    <Setter.Value>
                        <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type ListBoxItem}">
                            <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                                <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                                    <Label Content="FooLabel: "/>
                                    <TextBlock Text="{TemplateBinding Content}"/>
                                </StackPanel>
                            </StackPanel>
                        </ControlTemplate>
                    </Setter.Value>
                </Setter>
            </Style>
        </ListBox.ItemContainerStyle>
    </ListBox>
```

Answer (score -1):

You can add your codes to :

```
private void listBox1_Click(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
        {
           //Codes : 
        }
```

Or you can raise this event when you double click in the ListBox :

```
private void listBox1_DoubleClick(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        listBox1.Click+=listBox1_Click; 
    }
```

Update : If you want to do something after clicking on the item, actually when you click you are changing the index of selected item, then you're going to raise an event which called `listBox1_SelectedIndexChanged`. So all you have to do is add the codes in this event.

```
private void listBox1_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        //Your Codes .....
    }
```

Comment: Thanks for that ..I have no idea how can I invoke the selected item with it.can you guide me through.Also how can I do it in MVVM way

Comment: @kyle What do you want to do after clicking to item? are your items in listbox?

Comment: I want to put it in my `SelectedItem` but only on single click i.e mouse left button down

Comment: This answer completely miss the main point of it being MVVM related question